# Laravel 405 response using jQuery $.post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, post

I have the following route:

```
Route::post('leads/fields/{vertical_id?}/{lead_id?}', 'LeadController@fields')->name('leads.fields');
```

**I have disabled CSRF protection for this route just in case, even though I am also sending the token via form serialization.**

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).on('change', '#vertical_id', function () {
    var url = 'http://myapp.local/leads/fields/1/2';

    $.post(url, $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function (data) {
        $('#fields_html').html(data);
    });
});
```

I am getting a 405 response with an empty `message`. If I change my route to `Route::get` it works, but it does not give me the serialized form data.

Halp

**Edit: here is the stack trace:**

```
{
    "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 255,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 242,
            "function": "methodNotAllowed",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "getRouteForMethods",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 612,
            "function": "match",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 601,
            "function": "findRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 590,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 56,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 30,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 149,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 53,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 151,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\wamp64\\www\\projects\\infusedx\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: give some id to the form like `form1` the use it like `('#form1').serialize()`

Comment: That would change nothing. The jQuery I posted is firing from `change` of a select dropdown.

Comment: paste your error here which you are getting in the console

Comment: Can you try by adding Content-Type: application/json

Comment: If you're hitting a 301/302 redirect, that would change the POST to a GET. Do you have a redirect from http to https, or anything else like that?

Comment: i have added the stack trace to the OP